# Pandas apply : function prototype for automatic column unpacking

Tags: python, pandas, apply

Is there a way I can use to make a function unpack the columns automatically with df.apply method?

Ideally, I am looking for a way to define the function such that it automatically unpacks regardless of the number of columns in the data frame and allows me to use the column names as variables directly
Something like

```
def func(*row):
    print col1
or def func(**row)
    print col1
```

along with `df.apply(func, axis=1)`

What I've tried so far and did not like

```
def func(row):
       col1, col2, col3 = row
```

`df[col1, col2, col3].apply(func, axis=1)`

Example as requested:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

grid = np.random.rand(5,2)
df = pd.DataFrame(grid, columns =['col1', 'col2'])
```

Given this: I am trying to write a function such that

```
def multiply(x): 
###This function definition does not obviously work. What im asking is a way to achieve similar functionality without me explicitly unpacking x to col1 and col2###
    print col1
    print col2


df.apply(multiply, axis=1)
```

Comment: please add an example of input data and the expected output. Right now it is hard to see what you're trying to achieve

Comment: Thanks I've edited with an example

Comment: Using the example, did you try to use `x['col1']`? .apply function is expected to get a series, in case `axis=1` it is a row and columns are the index of this series

Answer (score 0):

If you use `apply` with a function and `axis=1` then the columns are already accessible by their names.

```
def print_columns(row):

    print('Column 1:', row['col1'])
    print('Column 2:', row['col2'])

df.apply(print_columns, axis=1)
```

From the `row` variable in the function you can access any columns by name. Obviously make sure you `return` something to set in the output column.